# What is the equivalent (if any) of ssh-agent on Windows?

Tags: remote-access, ssh, windows-server

ssh-agent can prevent you from having to enter passphrases into your public key's when connecting to a remote server on Linux; thus enabling you to automate remote tasks over a secure channel.

Is there any sort of Windows-native equivalent for this sort of thing on Windows other than using Cygwin?  I'm aware of a feature of Windows called Windows-Vault, but I don't think that's quite the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), the associated Pageant program performs this function.

Comment: I'm aware of PuTTY...but what if you work in an environment where you're connecting to a Windows box?  I have psexec, but I don't like the security on it.  What of powershell remote commands, are they secure?

Comment: Pageant is a client-side thing, just like ssh-agent, it doesn't matter what kind of server you're connecting to.